# Batch Script to Create Multiple Folders within Multiple Folders

Tags: batch-file

I have tried a bunch of things and a lot of research but nothing I've tried has done what I need.

I'm trying try create a folder structure of multiple folders within another folder. The names of the folders are separated by commas in a batch script loop.

I now need to create another heap of subfolders but I need them to be beneath the first level subfolder that was created by the other list separated by commas folder names.

**Example Folder Structure**

> ```
>  - Main folder
>    - Sub folder A
>       - Sub folder 1
>       - Sub folder 2
>       - Sub folder 3
>       - Sub folder 4 
>    - Sub folder B
>       - Sub folder 1
>       - Sub folder 2
>       - Sub folder 3
>       - Sub folder 4 
>    - Sub folder C
>       - Sub folder 1
>       - Sub folder 2
>       - Sub folder 3
>       - Sub folder 4
> ```

I've managed to create all the "main" sub-folders `A,B,C` but I have had no luck in creating the sub-folders `1,2,3..` from the new heap beneath the first heap of sub-folders create as `A,B,C`

```
for %%x in (A,B,C) do md %%x
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a variable with the `A,B,C` set, create another variable with the `1,2,3,4` set, and then put each set in a nested [FOR](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) loop and iterate each variable value accordingly from each set to get `A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3` and so forth ensuring every combination is iterated.

You just use the [MD](https://ss64.com/nt/md.html) command to create the directory combinations appended to the root directory where the main subfolders from group A set separated by commas will reside.

### Script Example

Be sure to set the  `RootDir=` value as the full path to the parent folder that will contain the group A list folders that are set as the `SubA=` variable.

```
@ECHO ON
SET RootDir=C:\Main
SET SubA=A,B,C,D,E
SET SubB=1,2,3,4,5
FOR %%A IN (%SubA%) DO FOR %%B IN (%SubB%) DO IF NOT EXIST "%RootDir%\%%~A\%%~B" MD "%RootDir%\%%~A\%%~B"
EXIT
```

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [MD](https://ss64.com/nt/md.html)

Comment: You can skip the IF exist if you redirect the ouput to 2>nul.

Comment: @harper Please comment back example syntax using the `FOR %%A IN (%SubA%) DO FOR %%B IN (%SubB%) DO IF NOT EXIST "%RootDir%\%%~A\%%~B" MD "%RootDir%\%%~A\%%~B"` part of the logic from my example when you get a chance so I can test this to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Given a layout of e.g.:

```
Main Folder 
     Sub Folder A
        Sub Folder 1
        [...]
        Sub Folder 4
     Sub Folder B 
        Sub folder 1 
        [...]
        Sub Folder 4 
     [...]
```

The simplest answer (even if it is rather tedious and brute force) is to simply write out `mkdir` lines for each final subfolder:

```
mkdir "Main Folder\Sub Folder A\Sub Folder 1"
mkdir "Main Folder\Sub Folder A\Sub Folder 2"
mkdir "Main Folder\Sub Folder A\Sub Folder 3"
mkdir "Main Folder\Sub Folder A\Sub Folder 4"
```

Repeat this as many times as you need and simply change the folder names.

If a directory doesn't initially exist, it will be created. If it does exist, a folder will be created in it. So the very first line:

```
mkdir "Main Folder\Sub Folder A\Sub Folder 1"
```

will create all three folders shown whereas this line:

```
mkdir "Main Folder\Sub Folder Z\Sub Folder 1"
```

creates only the 2nd and 3rd folder (since `Main Folder` already exists).

As you indicated you wanted special characters (spaces and commas), you'll need to wrap each command with quotes (as shown). For folders *without any* special characters (e.g. `Folder1\Folder2` ), quotes are unnecessary.

I haven't included drive letters since I am assuming the .bat file will be in the same directory as where you wish to create `Main Folder` and its subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

powershell might do it.

```
$root = "\\*\folderA"

ForEach ($dir in (Get-Item -Path "$root\*\" | ?{$_.PSIsContainer})){

If (!(Test-Path -Path "\*\FolderA")) {

    New-Item -Path "$root\*\" -Name "Folder1" -ItemType Directory | Out-Null

}

}
```

Just repeat the `New-Item -Path "$root\*\" -Name "Folder1" -ItemType Directory | Out-Null` part for each subfolder

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be:

```
mkdir -p main_folder/{bio,gallery,home,howto,infofeeds,links,projects}/{static,templates}
```